# What would be a very efficient on-board camera?

Tags: camera

I can't decide myself to buy an on board camera ... There are many models, some of them, very expensive.

On Amazon.com, there are many models, most of which have received no rating. Thus, choosing a camera which is actually durable, usage, has a multi-hour battery life is like trying to catch a butterfly with eyes closed.

Here are my wishes :
- can record about 2 to 4 hours non-stop
- has a shifting feature (keeps in memory only the last 4 hours, like surveillance camera systems)
- provides with a really decent image (1280x768 is a minimum!) at a real 30im/s frame rate, no flicker due to weak CPU etc...
- is small enough not to draw attention (Go Pro would be ok, but it is big and expensive and would probably not handle 2 to 4 hours recording. Correct me if I'm wrong)
- can easily be mounted in at the front AND the back of the vehicle.

Would you have any recommendations ?

EDIT: Thank you for the comments encouraging me to extend the question, to salvage it from the appetite of hungry moderators.

**EDIT2:** I want evidence in case of an accident and at the same time, I'd like the camera to be as stealthy as possible.

Comment: This question is salvageable, with some more information. Please edit it to explain exactly what you are looking for in the camera and exactly the purpose of the camera. I am not sure if you are talking about a backup camera or a crash camera. [Please see this post to help you edit your question](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/174/85) @RoryAlsop  I would disagree based on the linked post.

Comment: I agree with @Larry that it may be salvaged, though it may take some work. I do, however, vote to close as it is now, but I would retract the vote, or vote to reopen, should this situation been rectified.

Comment: @theUg : I fortunately rectified the situation!

Comment: Hi Skippy - updated my answer based on your question. Much more useful now, as we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RoryAlsop: superb ! Thanks for the guidance in improving the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

For recording evidence in the event of an accident, key requirements will include the following in addition to your criteria:

- Ideally two cameras, fore and aft facing
- Relatively wide angle cameras will be useful
- Mounted within the car, so you can provide evidence of your actions (remember this could count against you if an accident is your fault!)
- Storage relatively central in the car, or at least within the passenger compartment, to avoid destruction

Two off-the-shelf solutions that could suit you well are [Dogcam](http://www.dogcamsport.co.uk/motorsports-car-camera-kits.htm) and [EverFocus](http://www.everfocusonline.co.uk/index.php?route=product/category&path=113&gclid=CJ715eewjbUCFe_MtAodej0AKQ) - but there are endless numbers of project versions detailed on the Internet. Computer-based PVR solutions give you the most flexibility but are generally the most costly.

Also, for evidence, your criteria are a little over-specified. You don't need 30fps and high resolution for evidence to be useful - they can help, and high resolution lets the camera pick up number plates etc from a greater distance, but even a 15 fps, black and white camera can be useful.

I think a GoPro set to its lowest settings has a pretty long record time, and generally whatever solution you use will be hooked in to the ignition so battery is rarely an issue.

Comment: Having evidence in the event of an accident would be my goal. Thanks for your detailed reply.